# Adjective/noun for creating a payment schedule

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's say I'm creating a payment schedule for a real estate contract. The price is X and I need to create five payments that amount to X over the next year.

What is the (ideally professional) word for what I need to do?

Click the button to __________ the payments.
or
Click the button to view the payment ____________.

I belive in the UK "spread" is used. But is there another term in US English?

EDIT: Clarification here - I want the term for action done to the complete contract amount in the planning stage, and not the actual payment (amortization is a great word but was defined as the payment of).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use anything like *compute* or *calculate*? Or *display*? Any of those would fit in the space. You seem to be not giving the full information.

Comment: Amortization is the act of spreading the total repayment over time, which I believe addressed your question as originally asked. The *actual* payment (or the *amount* thereof) is called an ***installment*** (single **l** in US spelling), as noted in @fev's answer and comment.

Comment: Are you able to reword the instructions? *Click the button to create payment installments. Click the button to view the payment installments.*

Comment: I am a bit confused. You want an adjective/noun for "creating" a payment schedule?? If I understand you correctly, you want a "verb" for creating the payment schedule, i.e., splitting the total sum over several payment periods. However, you also want a word for the resulting "noun", i.e., the payment schedule. Then, schedule is your word; I don't believe the nouns "payment spread" or "payment space(d) (out) (payment)" are commonly used.

Comment: Could you clarify why you are speaking about an adjective and further specify what you are precisely looking for? And could you add a bit more clarification on why you reject amortization as it was discussed to be quite fitting under certain circumstances, particularly (and maybe not even exclusively), if you are not exactly looking for only the process of "creating a schedule"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ***space (out)***, but *spread* is the most common. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spaced) gives this example:

> If you're in financial difficulty, we're happy to let you ***space (out) your payments*** (= p*ay in smaller amounts over a longer period of time*) over two years.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spaced%20payment) defines ***spaced payment*** as:

> the payment of parts of a purchase price at stated intervals : payment by installments.

Comment: @Anton M-W is an American dictionary so it spells _installments_. I think it is alright to leave it as the dictionary has it.

Comment: I know M-W is American - that's one of its charms. I should have checked.

Answer (score 1):

NOUN - [***amortization***](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/accounting/amortization/)  <sup>(corporatefinanceinstitute.com)</sup>

> *The amortization of a loan is the process to pay back, in full, over time the outstanding balance.*

VERB - [***amortize***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amortize) <sup>(Merriam-Webster)</sup>

> *to pay off (an obligation, such as a mortgage) gradually usually by periodic payments of principal and interest or by payments to a sinking fund*

Comment: The Full OED has **amortise** definition 4 (transitive) *To pay off (a debt) gradually by making regular repayments over a period of time. Also occasionally intransitive: to be paid off in this way.* It's a trivial extension from those exact senses to ***define a schedule** of regular repayments...* as per [this written example](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22accountant+will+amortise+the+debt%22) - *Your accountant will **amortise the debt** (**work out the monthly repayment amount** over many months including all interest and capital repayment).*

Comment: I deleted my last comment; the term is relevant in a way. However, since we are talking about (a) technical term(s) here, I am not entirely sure if it is a trivial extension from "paying of a dept" to "creating a schedule". And with all due respect, the source you provided is not ideal. I am absolutely sure that you can create an amortization schedule, just not so sure whether creating that schedule should be called "amortize". In the given context you can certainly say "amortize the payments"; but, doesn't that mean "starting the process of paying it of", which includes creating a schedule?

Comment: I've been quite happily using ***amortise*** in various closely-related "extended" senses for over half a century, and I'm not aware anyone has ever had a problem understanding me. As well as using it transitively / intransitively to mean *pay off / be paid off in installments*, it's perfectly natural to use it to mean ***make arrangements for the AMORTISATION** [of a debt]*. Not *every* trivial extension from a "base" definition needs to be spelled out by dictionaries.

Comment: Note that to "amortise the payments" would normally be understood to mean *make the arrangements*. Doing that wouldn't normally imply actually *starting* to make payments - it would simply define *when and how much* those (planned future) payments would be.

Comment: That was exactly my point and what I ment with "starting the process of paying it of", i.e., "make arrangements for the amortisation". However, I still think that there are more precise ways of referring to the "process of making the schedule". If you tell youre employee to "amortize the payments" and you expect to receive a schedule, then it might go right, it might also go wrong and he'll pay the debt for you. But I also understand that language works a lot with context; however, still, I think there are more precise ways of refering to "creating the schedule" with the result of "a schedule"

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply *schedule* used in the following way?

> Click the button to schedule payments.

and

> Click the button to view payment schedule.

The word *plan* would also work well if you prefer it, as a set of scheduled payments is often referred to as a *payment plan*, but in my experience, that term has a consumer connotation more than a professional connotation.